# Разместить GO по центру

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d, камера

Всем привет.

Есть GameObject, нужно, чтобы при запуске сцены, он размещался ровно посредине камеры. Как это можно реализовать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: 2d или 3d?...........или он пустой это GameObject?

Comment: 3D, камера находится под углом. GameObject - растянутый куб

Answer (score 3):

```
gameObject.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
```

Comment: а если игра 3d?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда рейкаст в помощь: `Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(vec);`

Comment: Я к тому, что, возможно, расположение камеры имеет значение.... сверху снизу сверху-чутьполубоку....... я поэтому не стал писать какой-либо ответ, птмчт нипанятна точно...... хотя конечно процент того что это 2d - велик

Comment: Достаточно в примере задать z составляющую для вектора, чтобы сместить объект на нужное расстояние от камеры

Comment: Игра 3D, камера находится под углом.

Comment: @НикитаМедведев я вам дал ответ для 2д и для 3д.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов данным способом не получается. Объект появляется на уровне камеры (их z-координаты равны). Даже если её приравнять к нулю, центр объекта не находится в центре камеры.

Comment: @НикитаМедведев если у вас корректная камера, то объект должен появиться по центру. Если этого не происходит, вероятно у вас что то не так с камерой, или вы делаете что то не так.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов я после этого приравнял y координату к 0, а z координату поделил на тангенс угла наклона по оси z. Вроде бы получилось